# RSI indicator with Buy Stop Order

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I understand buy stop appears when the price is above the current market price.

I need to understand why does the Buy stop order appear here. I don't quite understand how does RSI Signal Indicator affects the buy stop ?

This is the code

```
//if above 70 , overbought , if below 30, then oversold
strategy(title="Stop Order RSI Strategy", shorttitle="Stop Order RSI", format=format.price, precision=2)

//Inputs
i_oversold = input(30 , title="Oversold")
i_overbought = input(70 , title="Overbought")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)

//Calculations
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

//Plotting
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")

goLong = rsi < i_oversold
goShort = rsi > i_overbought
strategy.entry("Buy Stop" , stop=high , when = goLong , long = true)
strategy.entry("Sell Stop" , stop=low , when = goShort , long = strategy.short)
```

[image]

Appreciate if someone can take their time to explain what is going on here because I am very lost.

Comment: I've put that piece of code into a strategy. It doesn't generate a signal at that bar. Please edit your question and post the whole script.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen I have already updated and pasted the whole script. Thank you very much for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is behaving correctly.
This is my rendition of your code, with added `//@version=4` as the first line, and a debug section at the end.

```
//@version=4
//if above 70 , overbought , if below 30, then oversold
strategy(title="Stop Order RSI Strategy", shorttitle="Stop Order RSI", format=format.price, precision=2)

//Inputs
i_oversold = input(30 , title="Oversold")
i_overbought = input(70 , title="Overbought")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)

//Calculations
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

//Plotting
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")

goLong = rsi < i_oversold
goShort = rsi > i_overbought
strategy.entry("Buy Stop" , stop=high , when = goLong , long = true)
strategy.entry("Sell Stop" , stop=low , when = goShort , long = strategy.short)

// === DEBUG ===
plotchar(rsi, "rsi", "")
plotchar(i_oversold, "i_oversold", "")
plotchar(i_overbought, "i_overbought", "")
plotchar(goLong, "goLong", "")
plotchar(goShort, "goShort", "")
```

When you hover over a bar, the debug section shows the value of the variables at that bar in the data window, like this:
[image: Data window]

On `11 Mar '20` you see that `goLong` is `0`.

On `12 Mar '20` you see that `goLong` becomes `1`.
That means that Pine will look to go long on the *next* bar, with a stop order at the `high` of the *current* bar.
So, it's looking to go long on `13 Mar '20` at `16.6427452`, which is the high of `12 Mar '20`.
On `13 Mar '20`, this stop price is never reached, so it does not go long.

On that same `13 Mar '20`, you see that `goLong` is still `1`.
The same process repeats. Pine will look to go long on the *next* bar, with a stop order at the `high` of the *current* bar. So, it's looking to go long on `14 Mar '20` at `12.3718699`, which is the high of `13 Mar '20`.
Again, on `14 Mar '20`, this stop price is never reached, so it does not go long.

On `14 Mar '20`, you see that `goLong` is still `1`.
The same process repeats again. Pine will look to go long on the *next* bar, with a stop order at the `high` of the *current* bar. So, it's looking to go long on `15 Mar '20` at `11.4392802`, which is the high of `14 Mar '20`.
This time, on `15 Mar '20`, this stop price is reached, and the system enters a long position.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I find it very difficult to understand how does this work . Under what circumstances does this Buy Stop gets triggered ? I understand that it gets triggered when it goes Long. So why doesn't it trigger when goLong = 1? I am still new to this , how can I understand what is going on ?

Comment: This is explained in my answer. It **tries** to go long on every `goLong=1`, but it can only  **enter** a long position when the stop price is reached. So both conditions must be true before it can enter long. I suggest you open the data window and see for yourself how the values changes on each bar. I don't think I can make it any more clear than that.